# How to detect react state change on browser tab switching?

Tags: reactjs

When a user logged in as a customer, he stays in the system under his role even if he changes the browser tab. My client has credentials for admin as well as for the customer. Testing the app he logged as a customer and decided to open a new tab and login as an admin. When he did back on the first tab,  surprisingly he had an admin view instead of the customer. My question is, is it possible somehow to detect state change when the other browser tabs were active? I am storing the token in localStorage for API calls, rest data (email, username etc) in redux.

Comment: Presumably when he logged in with admin credentials on the new tab he got a new admin token to put in local storage? Refreshing the page logged in as customer will resend any initial API calls with the new admin token. Every time you load/refresh a new tab of the site you are loading a fresh instance - two tabs running the same site do not share any state, and you cannot access one from the other for security reasons. That's what local storage is for, to persist user information between sessions.